# Crash on Open APP with gluonmobile and graalVM

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile, graalvm

My app is based on gluon mobile and graalVM. I have 3 ios device:
1) iPhone 8 iOS 13.3.1
2) iPhone 6s versione ios 13.3.1
3) iPhone Xr versione ios 13.3.1

On the last device my app crash at the startup. I've tried to check the log but is very incomprensibile. How I can do to solve my problem?

This is my log on crash with iPhone Xr versione ios 13.3.1, I take it with usb device and I launch mvn client:run:

```
   [ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB] 2020-02-21 12:45:24.694404+0100 fsmainapplication[2191:521772] [AttachLog] Notch is TOP
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB] [AttachLog] 2020-02-21 12:45:24.695 void sendNotch():149 Notch is TOP
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB] tive code filled the stack, and now there is not even enough stack space left to throw a regular StackOverflowError; 3) An internal VM error occurred.
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB] 
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB] JavaFrameAnchor dump:
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB] 
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB]   Anchor 000000016f3da598 LastJavaSP 000000016f3da570 LastJavaIP 0000000100f6a598
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB]   
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB] TopFrame info:
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB] 
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB]   TotalFrameSize in CodeInfoTable 48
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB]   
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB] VMThreads info:
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB] 
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB]   VMThread 00000002830980c0  STATUS_IN_NATIVE  jdk.internal.misc.InnocuousThread@0x1198279a0
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB]   VMThread 0000000283084000  STATUS_IN_NATIVE  java.lang.Thread@0x11a95a610
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB]   VMThread 00000002830986c0  STATUS_IN_JAVA (safepoints disabled)  java.lang.Thread@0x118c17978
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB]   VMThread 0000000283088480  STATUS_IN_NATIVE  java.lang.Thread@0x119201028
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB]   VMThread 00000002830880c0  STATUS_IN_NATIVE  java.lang.Thread@0x118c04218
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB]   VMThread 000000028309c240  STATUS_IN_NATIVE  java.lang.Thread@0x112f02990
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB]   VMThread 000000028308c000  STATUS_IN_NATIVE  java.lang.Thread@0x1058f3b50
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB]   
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB] VM Thread State for current thread 00000002830986c0:
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB] 
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB]   0 (8 bytes): com.oracle.svm.jni.JNIThreadLocalEnvironment.jniFunctions = (bytes) 
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB]     00000002830986c0: 0000000103b975c8
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB]   
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB]   8 (32 bytes): com.oracle.svm.core.genscavenge.ThreadLocalAllocation.regularTLAB = (bytes) 
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB]     00000002830986c8: 0000000119800000 0000000119900000
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB]     00000002830986d8: 00000001198a0c90 0000000000000000
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB]     
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB]   
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB]   40 (8 bytes): com.oracle.svm.core.heap.NoAllocationVerifier.openVerifiers = (Object) null
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB]   48 (8 bytes): com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.IdentityHashCodeSupport.hashCodeGeneratorTL = (Object) java.util.SplittableRandom  000000011980c3f8
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB]   56 (8 bytes): com.oracle.svm.core.snippets.SnippetRuntime.currentException = (Object) null
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB]   64 (8 bytes): com.oracle.svm.core.thread.JavaThreads.currentThread = (Object) java.lang.Thread  0000000118c17978
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB]   72 (8 bytes): com.oracle.svm.core.thread.ThreadingSupportImpl.activeTimer = (Object) null
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB]   80 (8 bytes): com.oracle.svm.jni.JNIObjectHandles.handles = (Object) com.oracle.svm.core.handles.ThreadLocalHandles  00000001198010d0
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB]   88 (8 bytes): com.oracle.svm.jni.JNIThreadLocalPendingException.pendingException = (Object) null
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB]   96 (8 bytes): com.oracle.svm.jni.JNIThreadLocalPinnedObjects.pinnedObjectsListHead = (Object) null
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB]   104 (8 bytes): com.oracle.svm.jni.JNIThreadOwnedMonitors.ownedMonitors = (Object) null
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB]   112 (8 bytes): com.oracle.svm.core.genal.snippets.StackOverflowCheckImpl.yellowZoneStateTL = (int) -16843010  fefefefe
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB]   172 (4 bytes): com.oracle.svm.core.snippets.ImplicitExceptions.implicitExceptionsAreFatal = (int) 0  00000000
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB]   176 (4 bytes): com.oracle.svm.core.thread.Safepoint.safepointRequested = (int) 2147359570  7ffe1b52
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB]   180 (4 bytes): com.oracle.svm.core.thread.ThreadingSupportImpl.currentPauseDepth = (int) 0  00000000
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB]   184 (4 bytes): com.oracle.svm.core.thread.VMThreads$StatusSupport.safepointsDisabledTL = (int) 1  00000001
[ven feb 21 12:45:24 CET 2020][INFORMAZIONI] [SUB]   188 (4 bytes): com.oracle.svm.core.thread.VMThreads$StatusSupport.statusTL = (int) 1  00000001
```

Comment: So it fails only in one of the three devices? Does HelloFX works on that device? How do you deploy, via USB (you should see the console) or via TestFlight (you can see symbolicated logs from Xcode)

Comment: the app crash only with device 3. During the crash I can't view the log becose the popup for send log to TestFlight dosen't appear.

Comment: You can plug your iPhone and open Xcode. From Xcode -> Window -> Devices and Simulators you have access to your phone crash logs

Comment: This is the error: 
Baseband Version:    10.80.02
Report Version:      104
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000c478ac9e7b8
VM Region Info: 0xc478ac9e7b8 is not in any region.  Bytes after previous region: 13490136410041  
      REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      MALLOC_NANO            0000000280000000-00000002a0000000 [512.0M] rw-/rwx SM=PRV

Comment: Nothing can be done with that... Edit your question and post something more meaningful, like the thread that crashed, and the re-symbolicated stacktrace.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't match iOS 13.3.1, also date is from more than a week ago. Are you sure this is the right crash log?

Comment: In the question I have posted the complete log. Anyway I continue to study the problem. if you want other info I'll get you.

Comment: Maybe you can save the full console output into a log file and share it?

Comment: How I can share the log file? I post the content in the question?

Comment: Long content is not allowed, you can share a link to your file hosted elsewhere, like Dropbox or pastebin

Comment: I solved. The crash is caused by the SplashView of Gluon. I skeep this view and my app is shonw correctly

Comment: Thanks for reporting, I'll try to see if I can reproduce it.